# Identify specific HID device using windows rawinput API

Tags: c, windows, hid, raw-input

I want to control the rumble motors on an xbox 360 controller and to do so I need to open a file on the device. How do I determine which device to open, that is, which is the controller/gamepad?

I'm aware that you can get vendor strings and such but not all devices have those, and the path obtained from RIDI_DEVICENAME seems a meaningless string of numbers. I assume I need to open the "top level collection" and use that to find my device, maybe? How do I do this?

My current way of opening the device is getting a RAWINPUTDEVICELIST structure and simply changing the index into the list of devices until my program doesn't crash e.g in main():

```
...
    /* get number of rawinput devices attached to the system */
    UINT n_devices = cr_enumerate_devices();

    /* each device gets a struct */
    size_t size = sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST) * n_devices;

    /* 'array' of RAWINPUTDEVICELIST */
    PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST device_list_array = cr_safe_malloc(size);

    /* populate the array with GetRawInputDeviceList() */
    cr_get_device_list(device_list_array, n_devices);

    /* get path from RIDI_DEVICENAME */
    const char *path = cr_get_device_info(device_list_array[1].hDevice);

    /* open device, get handle */
    hid_device_global = cr_open_device(path);
...
```

As you can see this would crash if there is ever no device for element 1 in the device list.